# JOptionPane Input Dialog Cancel Button Is entering a Do While Loop

Tags: java, do-while, joptionpane

In the `do while` loop it checks if the user inputs any letters or `0` an that works well but when i click on the `cancel` button in the `JOptionPane` it enters the loop again instead of exiting the`JOptionPane`

```
do {
     try {

          op = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How Many Elements do you want in the universe?");
          opi = Integer.parseInt(op);

            if (op.equals("0")) {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Universe cannot be empty");

                    try_Error = false;

                } else {

                    try_Error = true;
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter Numbers Only");
                try_Error = false;
            }

        } while (!try_Error);
```

Comment: @Aaron It's a `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` the `Ok` and `cancel` button is in it

Comment: Test to see what the JOptionPane returns when cancel his pressed. Print the result out. Then test for that in your code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It Prints `Enters Numbers Only`

Comment: No, you misunderstand me, -- what it **returns**.  Print out the contents of the `op` variable immediately after it has been assigned the return value from the JOptionPane and see what it holds.

Comment: I *know* what it holds and could just tell you, but you need to learn how to discover these things yourself, and then change your code accordingly.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Oh `op` Returns `null`

Comment: ***EXACTLY***. So test for null and act on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141794/discussion-between-blazepage001-and-hovercraft-full-of-eels).